# Applying Css3 Transition on single image

Tags: html, css, transition

I want to apply a Css3 Transition Effect on a single Image But its not showing any effect after mouse over . My code is 

Html

`<img src="img/seats.png" id="img1"  />`

And Css

`#img1{`
`width:600px;`
`height:600px;`
`transition:width 3s;`
`-moz-transition:width 3s;`
`-webkit-transition:width 3s;`
`-o-transition:width 3s;`
`}`

`#img1:hover{`
`width:800px;`
`height:800px;`
`}`

But No effect showing on img1

Comment: seems to be working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ed9ngw88/

Comment: Always put the non prefixed property after the prefixed

Comment: Thanks imjared .its working now

Comment: i cant understand where was problem